# How to get the resolution and bitrate of a video using YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube, resolution, bitrate

i'm using the YouTube API v3 on android, but the API seems to have no interface to access the bitrate and resolution of a video.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, it is only possible to determine whether an video is in `HD` `or SD` (`contentDetails.definition`) if you are not the owner of the video.

You will get permissions-errors, while acccessing `fileDetails`